# Shepard Tour Guide JS isn't scrolling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the Shepherd tour guide working.

http://github.hubspot.com/shepherd/docs/welcome/

I have set scrollTo: true both globally and on each Shepherd tour stop, but the page jumps no matter what. Here is an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRvdKv

```
(function() {
var tour = new Shepherd.Tour({
  defaults: {
    classes: 'shepherd-theme-square',
    scrollTo: true
  }
});

tour.addStep('example', {
  title: 'Example Shepherd',
  text: 'This is the first step',
  attachTo: '#test1 bottom',
  advanceOn: '.docs-link click',
  scrollTo: true
});

tour.addStep('example', {
  title: 'Example Shepherd',
  text: 'This is the second step',
  attachTo: '#test2 bottom',
  advanceOn: '.docs-link click',
  scrollTo: true
});

tour.addStep('example', {
  title: 'Example Shepherd',
  text: 'This is the third step',
  attachTo: '#test3 top',
  advanceOn: '.docs-link click',
  scrollTo: true
});

tour.start();
})();
```

Am I just missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are expecting a smooth scroll to the element rather than an immediate jump? Shepherd uses the DOM API `Element.scrollIntoView()` to implement scrollTo. This does not do a smooth scroll. You can add your own scrollToHandler though. For example, with jQuery, you could change your constructor call to this:

```
var tour = new Shepherd.Tour({
      defaults: {
        classes: 'shepherd-theme-square',
        scrollTo: true,
        scrollToHandler: function(e) {
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(e).offset().top
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    });
```

This will then do an animated scroll. (Btw, there are many ways to do animated scrolling. The main point is to show how you would register one of these approaches.)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNByJJ